# Showing that a function stays above one

Tags: calculus, optimization

This is a rather elementary problem: Consider the following function

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\Big[ 1 - \frac{x^2}{(e^{x}-1)^2} \Big]
$$
defined on $[0,\infty)$. We have $f(0)=f(\infty)=1$ and plotting $f$ shows that $f \ge 1$ over the given interval. However, it doesn't seem easy to show this. A simple strategy is to show that $f' > 0$ for over $(0,a)$ and $f' < 0$ for $(a,\infty)$, for some unique $a > 0$ such that $f'(a)=0$. However, $f'$ does not have a  nice expression. I wonder if there is an easy way to show this? Taking logs helps a bit but not much.

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\Big[f(x)-1\Big]~dx ~=~ \zeta(2)-\dfrac32 ~=~ \dfrac{\pi^2}6-\dfrac32$

Comment: @Lucian, really? That is an interesting connection.

Comment: The whole idea is to expand $\dfrac1{1-e^{-x}}$ into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then to switch the order of summation and integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider
$$f(x)=1$$
Obviously $x=0$ is a solution. Considering only $x>0$, we can manipulate the equation into
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\Big[ 1 - \frac{x^2}{(e^{x}-1)^2} \Big]}{1-e^{-x}}&=1\\
\implies \frac{\Big[ e^{-x} - \frac{x^2}{(e^{x}-1)^2} \Big]}{1-e^{-x}}&=0\\
\implies e^{-x}=\frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)^2}\\
\implies e^x+e^{-x}=x^2+2
\end{align}$$
Does that have any solutions? First note that as $x\to0$, both sides equal 2. Next notice that both sides are increasing. Since that's the case, let's examine their derivatives. Notice that for $x>0$,
$$e^x-e^{-x}>2x$$
This can be seen by noticing that LHS is concave up on that interval and the RHS is the tangent line at $x=0$. Since the original equation had equality near $0$, and the derivative of the LHS is always bigger than the derivative of the RHS, it is always increasing faster and hence always greater. We have shown that for $x>0$,
$$e^x+e^{-x}>x^2+2$$
which means that the only solution to $f(x)=1$ is $x=0$..

What do we do with this? Well, we know that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, and the only solution to $f(x)=1$ is $x=0$. Also note that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$. This means that on $(0,\infty)$, $f(x)$ is greater than, equal to, or less than 1. Testing any point in that interval (for example $x=\ln2$) confirms that $f(x)$ is always greater than $1$. So we have shown that $f(x)\geq1$ on $[0,\infty)$, with equality only at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that $f(x)-1$ behaves rather nicely. It beats differentiating $f$ directly.